# GitLab API to post inline comment to Merge Request

Tags: gitlab

Using GitLab API it is possible to post a comment to a commit "on a particular line of a particular file" (see [here](https://docs.gitlab.com/ce/api/commits.html#post-comment-to-commit)).

On Merge Request in order to add comments it's required to use the *notes* resource (see [here](https://docs.gitlab.com/ce/api/notes.html#create-new-merge-request-note)) but the *note* object does not seem to contain any parameter to comment on a particular line.

However from the GitLab UI I'm able to add inline comments to a Merge Request in the Changes tab but when I call the API and look at the corresponding *note* object created from my inline comment there is nothing about the inline, it is only a regular *note* object without any line or line_type parameter...

**Anyone knows how to use the GitLab API to add inline comments to a Merge Request ?**

Answer (score 5):

### Code

`functions.yml`

```
.commit_comment:
  script:
    - export GITLAB_TOKEN="PROJECT_ACCESS_TOKEN"
    - |
      commit_comment() {
        curl --location --request POST "https://gitlab.com/api/v4/projects/$CI_MERGE_REQUEST_PROJECT_ID/merge_requests/$CI_MERGE_REQUEST_IID/notes" --header "PRIVATE-TOKEN: $GITLAB_TOKEN" --header "Content-Type: application/json" --data-raw "{ \"body\": \"$1\" }"
      }
```

### How to Use?

```
# ...
script:
    - !reference [.commit_comment, script]
    - commit_comment "YOUR_MESSAGE"
# ...
```

> ℹ️ Markdown is allowed for the message

### Generating Token

- Go to Your Project > Settings > Access Tokens
- Enter a Token name
- Choose `Reporter` as role
- Select the `api` scope. You can add more scopes but this is all we need here
- Generate the token

---

*P.s. Here, I have created a function to use with multiple jobs but you also directly use the `curl` command anywhere directly by replacing `$1` with your message.*

*[Ref](https://engineering.dunelm.com/how-to-post-a-custom-message-to-your-merge-request-using-gitlabci-3551824a1e5b)*

Comment: You have to be at least the  Premium tier to generate tokens.

Answer (score 3):

In order to add inline comments for merge requests, there is Discussions API: https://docs.gitlab.com/ce/api/discussions.html

Each discussion can contain a position in the code, like that:

```
    "position": {
      "base_sha": "b5d6e7b1613fca24d250fa8e5bc7bcc3dd6002ef",
      "start_sha": "7c9c2ead8a320fb7ba0b4e234bd9529a2614e306",
      "head_sha": "4803c71e6b1833ca72b8b26ef2ecd5adc8a38031",
      "old_path": "package.json",
      "new_path": "package.json",
      "position_type": "text",
      "old_line": 27,
      "new_line": 27
    },
```

Comment: not sure what you were after. I was looking for a way to log information on the build status in the MR (QG status to be specific). Your post clearly gave me what I was looking for. Kudos

Comment: When I try to use a `position` like that I get this error: `{"message":"400 (Bad request) \"Note {:line_code=\u003e[\"can't be blank\", \"must be a valid line code\"]}\" not given"}` and I can't for the life of me seem to find how to construct the mysterious `line_code` that appear here and there. Any pointers?

Comment: i'm having a similar issue @oskarth, I asked about it in a separate issue: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65926187/what-is-a-gitlab-line-code-as-referenced-when-creating-a-new-merge-request-threa

Answer (score 1):

I am using the python gitlab module and this is the format to add an inline comment. Please note that adding comments will fail If the line is not modified.

```
import gitlab
gl = gitlab.Gitlab(ci_server_url, oauth_token)
merge_request = gl.projects.get(project_id).mergerequests.get(merge_request_iid)

position = {
    "base_sha": merge_request.diff_refs["base_sha"],
    "head_sha": merge_request.diff_refs["head_sha"],
    "start_sha": merge_request.diff_refs["start_sha"],
    "new_path": "1.py",
    "new_line": 18,
    'position_type': 'text'
}

disc = merge_request.discussions.create({"body": "This is a comment on line 18", "position": position})
```

Comment: Thanks so much for this example. I am roaming the Internet for a while now to get his working...

Answer (score 0):

The notes API is used to only add comments to the Merge Request.

In order to add inline comments to the source code, you must use this other API endpoint:

https://docs.gitlab.com/ce/api/commits.html#post-comment-to-commit

But this API sets the comment in the commit list. You will not see the comment anywhere in the "Merge Request" page.