# What is a GitLab line_code as referenced when creating a new merge request thread

Tags: gitlab, gitlab-api

I'm trying to create a discussion note on a merge request on a certain line of a file with the GitLab api using this endpoint: https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/api/discussions.html#create-new-merge-request-thread

Part of the payload asks for a `line_code`

| Attribute | Type | Required | Description |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| position[line_range][start][line_code] | string | yes | Line code for the start line |

When I issue a POST I get a response with:

```
    "message": "400 (Bad request) \"Note {:line_code=>[\"can't be blank\", \"must be a valid line code\"], :position=>[\"is incomplete\"]}\" not given"
```

What is this `line_code`? Is it some kind of calculated value? The documentation is rather vague here.

When I issue a GET for all the current notes on a merge_request I can see some notes have this `line_code` (see below). I'm trying to figure out how to create that value for new notes.

```
 {
        "id": 89,
        "type": "DiffNote",
        "body": "4",
        "attachment": null,
        "author": {
            "id": 6,
            "name": "brian c",
            "username": "bc",
            "state": "active",
            "avatar_url": "https://www.gravatar.com/avatar/f590a9cf57136732dd0cb5z9b1563390?s=80&d=identicon",
            "web_url": "http://gitlab.mycompany.us/thisIsMe"
        },
        "created_at": "2021-01-11T21:46:23.861Z",
        "updated_at": "2021-01-11T21:46:23.861Z",
        "system": false,
        "noteable_id": 21,
        "noteable_type": "MergeRequest",
        "position": {
            "base_sha": "3bf8094f0d54fc70a66698bd582f25c77243de3b",
            "start_sha": "3bf8094f0d54fc70a66698bd582f25c77243de3b",
            "head_sha": "a10e73cf84eae38286df56f4b58fa221d7eefc44",
            "old_path": "b.txt",
            "new_path": "b.txt",
            "position_type": "text",
            "old_line": null,
            "new_line": 4,
            "line_range": {
                "start": {
                    "line_code": "aceba96ffdf13ce4cd4171c0248420cc03108ef0_0_4",
                    "type": "new",
                    "old_line": null,
                    "new_line": 4
                },
                "end": {
                    "line_code": "aceba96ffdf13ce4cd4171c0248420cc03108ef0_0_4",
                    "type": "new",
                    "old_line": null,
                    "new_line": 4
                }
            }
        },
        "resolvable": true,
        "resolved": false,
        "resolved_by": null,
        "confidential": false,
        "noteable_iid": 3,
        "commands_changes": {}
    },
```

Comment: Can you update your question with your use case for using the API to create comments?  It might help when answering your updates.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Line code is `hash of the file name + underscore +  old line number + underscore + new line number`

The documentation is wrong. `line_code` is required only if you are using `position.line_range` which is only required for adding diff note spanning multiple lines of diff. You don't need to deal with `line_code` for single-line diff notes. So it is not a required parameter. You can just use `position.old_line` or `position.new_line`.

Answer (score 1):

That represents the line in the file you want the comment to appear on. For Merge Requests, comments can either be on the code or general discussions (though the API names seem to be backwards).

To add a general discussion comment, you can use the Notes API: https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/api/notes.html#create-new-merge-request-note. This will look like the comment here: https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab/-/merge_requests/52673#note_495396729

To add a comment to the changed code in a Merge Request, you can use the Discussions API here: https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/api/discussions.html#create-new-merge-request-thread. This operation has options to set the file path and line number a comment should start on, a range that a comment applies to, etc. This is an example of a comment on the code itself: https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab/-/merge_requests/52673/diffs#2eda52c44979de93f257b305ada778372eacba0b_6_5

Comment: thanks! I added some additional details to the original post.

Answer (score 0):

It's not a bug, I meet this scene before.
maybe your "old_line" is not really exist.
just let set  old_line and old_path to null
it will work normally.